# What's the meaning of the phrase cite domain in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm playing this RPG video game Vampire The Masquerade and there is this group of vampires living on a beach. I walked up to them and started a conversation. The gang leader ask me if I came to run them off and I replied that I didn't. I asked him if it's common that someone does that. This is the answer he gave me I've trouble understanding.

"We're getting pretty sick of it. Someone **citing domain** or in the worst cases, hunting us for sport."

Now, I know the word "cite" means mention or refer to(TFD source below)
2. to mention in support, proof, or confirmation; refer to as an example: He cited instances of abuse.
...
Domain on the other hand has this definition on TFD which seems like it might fit here.
7. (Law) The land of one with paramount title and absolute ownership.

Does it mean that someone is referring to some kind of document of ownership when speaking to the vamps living on the beach?

Comment: You've got good definitions there. [This one](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/domain) might be even more targeted: "1 (law)
a: complete and absolute ownership of land:
*our highways and roads have been in the domain of state and local governments* —compare **EMINENT DOMAIN**"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it means that someone is **claiming** or **stating** "This is my domain, get out." That would be a rather loose use of "cite", but this is simulating very casual speech.

Comment: Can the domain be a written document as well? Like a document that entitles you to the land or property? Can he also mean that the people cite what is written on a legal document?

Comment: It is a game @Static Bounce  it can mean anything the game designer wants. But if someone said tha in real life I would not expect thjat a document was involved. This would be an unusual usage whatever it means, so one cannot be sure, but I think you are over fixing on the most common meaning of "cite" and ignoring possible meanings that fit the context a bit better.